# __getitem__ a 2d array

Tags: python, class

I am getting a weird error when trying to make the getitem method.

My code is:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    
    if (self.shape[0] == 1):
        return self.values[item]
    else:
        x, y = item 
        return self.twoDim[x][y]
```

I can't see where my mistake is, when I try

```
assert my_array[1][0] == 4
```

I get this error under:

```
x, y = item
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Any idea what the problem is?
Thank for any tips

Comment: The error is that you are trying to unpack item while there is not values to unpack, print item before this assignment to be sure what it stored there

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla Thank you, when I print I see the first value of the index, being 1 because of [1], any idea why it does not recognize [0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `array[0][1]` is first passing `0` into the `__getitem__` function, and then whatever the function returns, it passes `[1]` into that function. With your implementation, you cannot do this. You must input a tuple of values in the first `__getitem__` function:

```
class Array:

    def __init__(self):
        self.shape = (2, 2)
        self.values = None
        self.twoDim = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print(f"{item=}")
        if (self.shape[0] == 1):
            return self.values[item]
        else:
            x, y = item
            return self.twoDim[x][y]

array = Array()
try:
    print(array[1][0])       # item=1
except TypeError:
    pass
print("------")              
print(array[1, 1] == 4)      # item=(1, 1)
                             # True
```

Comment: hmm I see, a bit frustrating when I am told that accessing values should be like this: assert my_array[1][0] == 4, but I guess this is not possible because [1][0] need to be given as a tuple

Comment: @ili There are ways to get around it, but that is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: could you give me any tips to what to search for? and how to start working around it?

Comment: i will need your full class definition to help